# Issue with Authorize.net in Magento 2.3

Tags: checkout, orders, magento2.3, authorize.net, sandbox-mode

I have update my Magento version, Now the version is M2.3 and I installed the **Authorize.net** patch as well.

Now I am facing an issue is that -
1. Order is created in admin but on checkout, customer found the error message.
https://prnt.sc/n96fg2

2. I have got this email as well: https://prnt.sc/n96i3k
3. Admin settings: https://prnt.sc/n96jcp
4. Payment log:

> [2019-04-08 16:19:33] main.DEBUG: array (   'request' =>    array (
>       'x_version' => '3.1',
>       'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
>       'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
>       'x_test_request' => 'FALSE',
>       'x_login' => '****',
>       'x_method' => 'CC',
>       'x_relay_url' => 'http://test.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
>       'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
>       'x_fp_sequence' => '243',
>       'x_invoice_num' => '000000118',
>       'x_amount' => 10.04,
>       'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
>       'x_tax' => '0.00',
>       'x_freight' => '10.00',
>       'x_first_name' => 'Test',
>       'x_last_name' => 'Last',
>       'x_company' => '',
>       'x_address' => '3680  Maple Lane',
>       'x_city' => 'Huntsville',
>       'x_state' => 'South Carolina',
>       'x_zip' => '35801',
>       'x_country' => 'US',
>       'x_phone' => '2565123672',
>       'x_fax' => '',
>       'x_cust_id' => '',
>       'x_customer_ip' => '127.37.239.109',
>       'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
>       'x_email' => 'sun1@mailinator.com',
>       'x_email_customer' => '0',
>       'x_merchant_email' => 'test@malinator.com',
>       'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Test',
>       'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Marchant',
>       'x_ship_to_company' => '',
>       'x_ship_to_address' => '3680  Maple Lane',
>       'x_ship_to_city' => 'Huntsville',
>       'x_ship_to_state' => 'South Carolina',
>       'x_ship_to_zip' => '35801',
>       'x_ship_to_country' => 'US',
>       'x_po_num' => '',
>       'x_fp_timestamp' => 1554740373,
>       'x_fp_hash' => '381E8B94801B2015C5F1CF6E7F54F12D92DF0CCE7CA68836503C325E73035F904D89EE19C4BD89372AD9D7FBFBB9C38223065DC6DC45BAD1E2FCDE6652F6523F',
>   ), ) [] []

what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **gateway URL** and **transaction URL**. It seems to be that your using test URL. Please change it to

Gateway URL : https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Transaction URL: https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Do change this and try an test transaction.

Comment: Mohan, I am using my sandbox credentials that's why the URL is changed

Comment: If you are using sandbox account you can use the response message to see if the transaction is success or failure since time out error will occut, so once you are configuring your live credentials everything will work fine then

Comment: Currenlty, Orders are shown in admin but on checkout it is showing error message

Comment: Sandbox account do show time out errors in frontend, so we can identify if test transaction is success or failure only through response messages.